# Custom Wordpress menu replaces current header menu

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add an additional custom menu to a Wordpress theme. I've registered the menu and location in the functions.php file, created a new page template and added the menu. However whenever I add items to the menu it replaces everything in the main header but also adds it to where I need it to be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jack

> Below is my functions.php file. The menu I am trying to add is right
>   at the bottom called about-menu

```
        <?php
        function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
            $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
            return $mimes;
        }
        add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );
        ?>
        <?php add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); ?>
        <?php
        add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_next');
        add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_prev');

        function posts_link_next() {
            return 'class="next-button"';
        }

        function posts_link_prev() {
            return 'class="prev-button"';
        }; ?>
        <?php add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); ?>
        <?php
        /**
         * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
         *
         */
        function arphabet_widgets_init() {

            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'index-sidebar',
                'id' => 'index-sidebar-widget',
                'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-widget">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-sidebar">',
                'after_title' => '</h2>',
            ) );
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'announcement',
                'id' => 'announcement',
                'before_widget' => '<div class="announcement">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h2 class="announcement-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h2>',
            ) );

            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'tweets',
                'id' => 'tweets',
                'before_widget' => '',
                'after_widget' => '',
                'before_title' => '',
                'after_title' => '',
            ) );

            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'events',
                'id' => 'widget-events',
                'before_widget' => '',
                'after_widget' => '',
                'before_title' => '',
                'after_title' => '',
            ) );
        }
        add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );

        /*
         * Alters event's archive titles
         */
        function tribe_alter_event_archive_titles ( $original_recipe_title, $depth ) {

            // Modify the titles here
            // Some of these include %1$s and %2$s, these will be replaced with relevant dates
            $title_upcoming =   'Upcoming Events'; // List View: Upcoming events
            $title_past =       'Past Events'; // List view: Past events
            $title_range =      'Events for %1$s - %2$s'; // List view: range of dates being viewed
            $title_month =      'Events for %1$s'; // Month View, %1$s = the name of the month
            $title_day =        'Events for %1$s'; // Day View, %1$s = the day
            $title_all =        'All events for %s'; // showing all recurrences of an event, %s = event title
            $title_week =       'Events for week of %s'; // Week view

            // Don't modify anything below this unless you know what it does
            global $wp_query;
            $tribe_ecp = Tribe__Events__Main::instance();
            $date_format = apply_filters( 'tribe_events_pro_page_title_date_format', tribe_get_date_format( true ) );

            // Default Title
            $title = $title_upcoming;

            // If there's a date selected in the tribe bar, show the date range of the currently showing events
            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['tribe-bar-date'] ) && $wp_query->have_posts() ) {

                if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged' ) > 1 ) {
                    // if we're on page 1, show the selected tribe-bar-date as the first date in the range
                    $first_event_date = tribe_get_start_date( $wp_query->posts[0], false );
                } else {
                    //otherwise show the start date of the first event in the results
                    $first_event_date = tribe_event_format_date( $_REQUEST['tribe-bar-date'], false );
                }

                $last_event_date = tribe_get_end_date( $wp_query->posts[ count( $wp_query->posts ) - 1 ], false );
                $title = sprintf( $title_range, $first_event_date, $last_event_date );
            } elseif ( tribe_is_past() ) {
                $title = $title_past;
            }

            // Month view title
            if ( tribe_is_month() ) {
                $title = sprintf(
                    $title_month,
                    date_i18n( tribe_get_option( 'monthAndYearFormat', 'F Y' ), strtotime( tribe_get_month_view_date() ) )
                );
            }

            // Day view title
            if ( tribe_is_day() ) {
                $title = sprintf(
                    $title_day,
                    date_i18n( tribe_get_date_format( true ), strtotime( $wp_query->get( 'start_date' ) ) )
                );
            }

            // All recurrences of an event
            if ( function_exists('tribe_is_showing_all') && tribe_is_showing_all() ) {
                $title = sprintf( $title_all, get_the_title() );
            }

            // Week view title
            if ( function_exists('tribe_is_week') && tribe_is_week() ) {
                $title = sprintf(
                    $title_week,
                    date_i18n( $date_format, strtotime( tribe_get_first_week_day( $wp_query->get( 'start_date' ) ) ) )
                );
            }

            if ( is_tax( $tribe_ecp->get_event_taxonomy() ) && $depth ) {
                $cat = get_queried_object();
                $title = '<a href="' . esc_url( tribe_get_events_link() ) . '">' . $title . '</a>';
                $title .= ' &#8250; ' . $cat->name;
            }

            return $title;
        }
        add_filter( 'tribe_get_events_title', 'tribe_alter_event_archive_titles', 11, 2 );
        ?>
        <?php
        add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'ad_filter_menu', 10, 2);

        function ad_filter_menu($sorted_menu_objects, $args) {

            // check for the right menu to filter
            // here we check for the menu with name 'Posts Menu'
            // given that you call it in you theme with:
            //   wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Posts Menu' ) );
            // if you call the menu using theme_location, eg:
            //   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top_manu' ) );
            // check for:
            //   if ($args->theme_location != 'top_menu')
            if ($args->menu != 'Parents Menu')
                return $sorted_menu_objects;


            // edit the menu objects
            foreach ($sorted_menu_objects as $menu_object) {
                // searching for menu items linking to posts or pages
                // can add as many post types to the array
                if ( in_array($menu_object->object, array('post', 'page', 'any_post_type')) ) {
                    // set the title to the post_thumbnail if available
                    // thumbnail size is the second parameter of get_the_post_thumbnail()
                    $menu_object->title = has_post_thumbnail($menu_object->object_id) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($menu_object->object_id, 'full') . '<span class="outer"><span>' . $menu_object->title . "</span></span>": $menu_object->title;

                }
            }

            return $sorted_menu_objects;
        };

        ?>

        <?php

        function register_my_menu() {
          register_nav_menu('about-menu',__( 'About Menu' ));
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

        ?>
```

> The next code snippet is from my page template that I want to add the
>   menu to.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: About Us Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header();?>

<div class="main">
        <div class="page-top-banner" id="page-four-banner">
            <h1><span>About</span></h1>
        </div>


<div class="parental-inner">

   <?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'about-menu', 'container_class' => 'about_menu_class' ) ); ?>


       </div>






       <?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your register_my_menu function from functions php, and replace with the following:

Remove this:

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('about-menu',__( 'About Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Replace with this:

```
//nav
register_nav_menus(array(
  'main-menu' => __('Main Menu'),
  'about-menu' => __('About Menu'),
));
```

Does that output correctly on the page template?

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting me back to me.

I've changed the code and it displays on the page as it should be also overwrites the main navigation on the site. Very weird and I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: Ah, You'll need to specify a menu location for your main site nav, and then specify in your theme where you'd like this to display. I've edited the above code so you can see the change.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: No problem at all, If my response helped you, and you could mark my reply as the correct answer, that'd be awesome! :)